# how to use the result from a case statement in a calculation

Tags: case

I have a case statement that returns a date;

```
case when (ma.first_active_date is not null or ma.first_deemed_date is not null)
             then (least(nvl(ma.first_active_date,sysdate),nvl(ma.first_deemed_date,sysdate)))
             else (ma.status_date) end djf
```

How can i then calculate a count of years between the returned date and the sysdate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to simply plug in your case statement into an expression, without the `djf` alias, of course:

```
((case when (ma.first_active_date is not null or ma.first_deemed_date is not null)
             then (least(nvl(ma.first_active_date,sysdate),nvl(ma.first_deemed_date,sysdate)))
             else (ma.status_date) end) - sysdate) diff_from_sysdate
```